# Getting 'table or view does not exist' error in spite of having access

Tags: oracle

I have a table and granted all to a user. If I Ctrl-Click on the table name in Toad, I can see all it's grants.

But when I run a query using that table, I get the 
`ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` exception.

Any ideas?

Grants:

```
Grantee Privilege
WEBUSER ALTER
WEBUSER DELETE
WEBUSER INDEX
WEBUSER INSERT
WEBUSER SELECT
WEBUSER FLASHBACK
WEBUSER REFERENCES
WEBUSER ON COMMIT REFRESH
WEBUSER QUERY REWRITE
WEBUSER DEBUG
WEBUSER UPDATE
```

Comment: Please add your failing query as well.

Comment: It is a simple select statement, no need to post

Comment: If the select statement is so simple, you can place it here, right? You're making us guess what you wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution to this was to confirm, and modify, the privileges for these tables and function according to our development database.

Both systems have the same privileges and everything works.

I thought I had checked that but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a public synonym for the table in question?  If you don't have one and you want to access the table as someone else (`WEBUSER` in this case), then you need to prefix the table name with the schema owner name.

Comment: No there is not

Comment: Then, put the schema owner prefix while referencing tables.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the table was created with apostrophes?

If so, have a look at ALL_TABLES to see the correct spelling with regards to uppercase/lowercase. 
For example, if the table was created as "Your_Table" you need query it like this:

select * from OWNER."Your_Table";